# Can I safely spot seal drywall after sanding

Tags: repair, drywall, paint, sealing

I have recently removed wallpaper and sanded the walls in one of our bedrooms. I then applied an oil based pigmented sealer to 1 of the walls before realizing some other imperfections are present on that wall.

Will I run into any issues (color problems when applying top coat) if I sand back the affected area, apply filler, then sand and re apply pigmented sealer to that spot alone? Or will I need to re-seal the whole wall in 1 run

Comment: I can't imagine that you'd have problems by patching and re-sealing that spot (especially if you give the sealer a bit of a buffer around the patch).

Answer (score 2):

Should not have any problems, as the repaired surface will be the same composition as the rest of the wall.

The fact that you did the whole wall once is the best way to prevent "shiners" at the spot of repair, as long as the new sealer extends into what was done before.